# WordPress - text area linebreaks as seperate P tags (without creating empty p-tags where linebreaks where)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom textarea are that I normally just output using '`nl2br`'.  In this particular case I need to wrap them in separate Paragraph tags, instead of have `'<br/>'`.

I'm currently using this:

```
$memberDescription = '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', array_filter(explode("\n", get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'members_' . $z . '_description', true )))) . '</p>';
```

My issue is that when I echo this out, it also outputs empty Paragraph tags (im guessing where extra line breaks are).

Any tips or tricks on how to alter this to remove the empty P-tags, or have them not even outputted, to begin with, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried exploding on `"\r\n"`?

Comment: I had not!  Thank you!  that did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer was what @fubar described above:

```
$memberDescription = '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', array_filter(explode("\r\n", get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'members_' . $z . '_description', true )))) . '</p>';
```